# React's setState not working on button click

Tags: reactjs

I wrote following JSX according to docs but the state doesn't reflect changes according to button click.

What could be the reason?

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'react-datasheet/lib/react-datasheet.css';

export default class TableCode extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 1 }
  };

  handleButtonClick(event) {
    this.setState({ count: 2 })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-3" onclick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>Generate Code</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to change `onclick` to `onClick`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-3" onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>Count is {this.state.count}</button>
  );
}
```

In JSX, the capitalisation of the attributes is important and differ from regular HTML.

`class` should also be changed to `className`.

Answer (score 4):

First use an arrow function as it doesn't needs any binding.Plus `onclick` spelling was wrong as react uses camelCase `onClick`.

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { count: 1 }
    };
  
    handleButtonClick=(event) =>{

      this.setState({ count: 2 })
     //console.log(event);
    }
    
    render() {
      console.log(this.state.count);
  
      return (
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-3" onClick={()=>{this.handleButtonClick()}}>Generate Code</button>
      );
    }
```

Or second solution the way you wants it by bind method.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { count: 1 }
        this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)
      };
    
      handleButtonClick() {
        this.setState({ count: 2 })
      }
    
      render() {
        console.log(this.state.count);
        return (
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-3" onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Generate Code</button>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'react-datasheet/lib/react-datasheet.css';

export default class TableCode extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 1 }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-3" 
       onClick={() => this.setState({ count: 2})}>Generate Code</button>
    );
  }
}
```